# Struggling to get Greensock to animate locally

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

I'm working with greensock and I can't seem to get it to animate anything locally.

I copied and pasted my code into [codepen](http://codepen.io/SpeedyAkron/pen/qbyGXQ) and the animation is working correctly there. The only difference between the two are minor differences in the html file, which are pasted below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenLite.min.js"></script>

        <script src="animate.js"></script>          
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="blue">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can debug through the JS and see the console.log working and the TweenLite functions appear to be called without any errors, but there is no animation on the screen. I've tried in Edge, Chrome, IE11, and Firefox. None of them show any animations.

Comment: what are the minor differences exactly?

Comment: I forgot my link to code-pen in my original post. I added that in so you can see the code.

Comment: do you get any errors in your `console`?

Comment: No console errors. In debugging through the code it looks like the Greensock is being called, but no animations happen on screen.

Comment: I had this exact same error, that was caused by not loading the CSS plugin correctly : the tweens were running, but nothing happens visually.